# Show Image from shared folder in Flutter - Unsupported scheme 'file'

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to show a network image from a shared folder in my local network.

```
child: const FadeInImage(
              placeholder: AssetImage('assets/no-image.jpg'),
              image:
              NetworkImage( "file://servername/folder1/folder2/folder3/backview.png"),
              width: 130,
              height: 190,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
```

This is the error I get:

Invalid argument(s): Unsupported scheme 'file' in URI file://servername/folder1/folder2/folder3/backview.png

I also tried using FileImage and still no success.

Also, this app is intended to be used on the internal network, and not from the outside.
What is the proper way to handle this? Should I make an API just to retrieve these Images?